# how to specify a scene to load in blend4web web player

Tags: objects, blender-internal-render-engine, blend4web

How to specify a scene to load in blend4web web player?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The **load** attribute should be used to load a scene, this attribute contains relative path to a JSON file.
https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/web_player.html#webplayer-attributes